# why is this gtk code failing to load ui file properly?

Tags: c, xml, gtk

In the gtk4 [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html#building-applications) there is an example where the function `gtk_builder_add_from_file` is used to load a `builder.ui` file, I used the same code but I create the `builder.ui` using glade application, when I compile and run the program I don't get anything inside the window but the title is the same one I defined in the glade app

Here is the contents of the `builder.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">MyApp</property>
    <property name="default-width">440</property>
    <property name="default-height">250</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="exit_app" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="Button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

and this is the code I am using to load the file

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>

static void print_hello(GtkWindow * window, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Clicked");
}

// renders the application
static void activate(GtkApplication * app, gpointer * user_data)
{
    /* Construct a GtkBuilder instance and load our UI description */
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.ui", NULL);

    // connect signal handlers to the constructed widgets
    GObject * window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"MainWindow");
    gtk_window_set_application(GTK_WINDOW(window), app);


    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    // unload the builder (destroy)
    g_object_unref(builder);

}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    #ifdef GTK_SCRDIR
        g_chdir(GTK_SCRDIR);
    #endif

    GtkApplication * app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.application", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

it compiles fine and runs with out any errors but no button what so ever is shown inside the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using GTK3 builder UI code which may not be valid in GTK4.  For the given `builder.ui` file, `GtkBox` child properties have been removed in GTK4. See [relevant section](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-gtkbox-padding-fill-and-expand-child-properties) from docs.

So, removing `<packing> ... </packing>` should be enough for your code.

Alternately, you can use `gtk4-builder-tool` to convert your GTK3 UI definitions to GTK4 by running `gtk4-builder-tool simplify --3to4 --replace builder.ui` (Remove `--replace` flag to print the output to `stdout` without replacing the input file)

which gives the following output for your file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="title" translatable="1">MyApp</property>
    <property name="default-width">440</property>
    <property name="default-height">250</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="exit_app" swapped="no"/>
    <property name="child">
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="Button">
            <property name="label" translatable="1">button</property>
            <property name="focusable">1</property>
            <property name="receives-default">1</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: how do i install this tool `sudo apt install  gtk4-builder-tool ` does not seem to work properly

Comment: `gtk4-builder-tool` shall be available after installing `libgtk-4-bin` package (on any recent Debian and derivatives)